# array_search not finding string?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$className = "Class B: Wednesday 6pm";
// $studentArray is multidimensional array with student info

foreach($studentArray as $student) {
    echo array_search($className,$student);
}

// Contents of $student is 
Array
(
    [Groups] => 187,267
    [Birthday] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 1981-02-04 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [_IGTestScore] => 0
    [Email] => blank@blank.com
    [_IGClass1] => Class B: Wednesday 6pm
    [_IGAttendedClass1] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-17 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [FirstName] => Joe
    [Id] => 3
    [LastName] => Schmoe
)
```

The output of that is:

> _IGTestScore

If I do a var_dump on $className and $student['_IGClass1] I get:

> string(22) "Class B: Wednesday 6pm"
>
> string(22) "Class B: Wednesday 6pm"

Never had an issue with array_search before, but this has been driving me crazy, and can't seem to figure out what is going on here. It seems that any string search is coming out the same. But if I do a search for an integer, like 3, it will pull out "Id" correctly.

## UPDATE - whole multi-dimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Groups] => 187,267
            [Birthday] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 1981-02-04 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [_IGTestScore] => 0
            [Email] => blank@blank.com
            [_IGClass1] => Class B: Wednesday 6pm
            [_IGAttendedClass1] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-02-17 00:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [FirstName] => Joe
            [Id] => 3
            [LastName] => Schmoe
        )

)
```

Comment: Your `Class B: Wednesday 6pm` value in the array may have a space in the end, like this: `Class B: Wednesday 6pm `. And this might be the issue.

Comment: @Nordenheim - I showed the var_dump to show that they are both identical.

Comment: It works correctly for me (tested). Sure that one of the sub-arrays is not malformed? You have same result for each sub-array?

Comment: @fusion3k - I can change the needle to other string values (like Joe, blank@blank.com) but the result is the same. Any string element (FirstName, Email, etc.) will return as "_IGTestScore".

I can access the elements fine individually, such as $student['_IGClass1'] and the value returns fine.

Comment: Also you have to `var_dump($student['_IGTestScore'])`, not `_IGClass1`...  ッ

Comment: @fusion3k - yes, it returns (int)0

Comment: I guess it's not possible to publish here effective entire array as JSON due to privacy issue, right?

Comment: @fusion3k - I just added it above. This is in testing, so there was only 1 test contact on there right now.

Comment: `var_export` output would be more useful now than output from `var_dump`. Could you replace it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem... but I don't know the reason: for me, it is a mystery!

The problem is `_IGTestScore` as integer: if `_IGTestScore` is an integer, `array_search()` returns `_IGTestScore` ( In fact it returns `_IGTestScore` for any searchstring, even if they doesn't exists! ), if `_IGTestScore` is set to `'0'` (string) or to a positive integer, `array_search()` returns correct value!

It's a bug?

Someone have an explanation?

**Edit:**

Obviously, there is a solution: use the “strict” parameter:

```
array_search( $className, $student, True );
```

But... Why “Class B: Wednesday 6pm” == 0?

Comment: Strict worked for me, but still puzzled as why it would behave this way regardless.